# Interactively re-center a lidR plot

Tags: lidr

Is it possible to move the plot center of a lidR plot from within the plot visualization? For example, I try dragging and using up and down arrows, but it does not move the point cloud's position within the plot.

With the following example,

```
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package ="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile)
plot(las, size = 3, bg = "white")
```

I'm not able to zoom in very much from a bird's eye view to see the tallest tree (red top in the lower right hand side). Zooming always focuses on the center.

Comment: Use right mouse button

Comment: @JRR Thank you, works!